# Is it possible to sort questions by multiple criteria?

Tags: support, questions

For example, what if I want to view the newest, unanswered questions in a certain tag?

Comment: @codeMagic maybe I should just edit the question body as the question?

Comment: I don't understand. Edit it as what question?

Comment: So it would be something like "[android] is:q answers:0" then click the "newest" tab

Comment: Ah ok. I found you can also go Unanswered > Unanswered Tags.